what is the maximum bytes can written per file in LITTLEFS file system in ESP32 wroom 32E?
I have ESP32 Wroom 32e controller which having 4MB of flash memory,in that 1.2MB partition for spiff file handling.i want to send sensor datas to server through wifi.when wifi is not available,i need to write the sensor datas on the single file in flash.
what is the maximum bytes can written per file  in LITTLEFS file system in ESP32 wroom 32E?

Why not try writing a simple program to test this?

For LittleFS, the maximum file size in bytes is set in LFS_FILE_MAX and is standard set to 2147483647 (the max value of a int32_t). This is more than 2000MB, which is much more than 4MB of storage your ESP32 has. Hence, the maximum file size is practically limited by the flash size/size of the partition.
